# PHP using session_set_save_handler

Tags: php, session

Below is copied directly from the php manual, I'm not sure how to set this up, there are just two things I need to do..

1. write some code when the session is destroyed
2. set the session_cache_expire to 20 mins - do that in the class or as a separate call?

Do I need to run sessionsavehandler() for every instance, every time I have session_start on the page?  If someone could please outline the steps I need to take to use this class that would be great.

```
<?php
 new SessionSaveHandler();
 ?>

 <?php

class SessionSaveHandler {
     protected $savePath;
     protected $sessionName;

    public function __construct() {
         session_set_save_handler(
             array($this, "open"),
             array($this, "close"),
             array($this, "read"),
             array($this, "write"),
             array($this, "destroy"),
             array($this, "gc")
         );
     }

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName) {
         $this->savePath = $savePath;
         $this->sessionName = $sessionName;
         return true;
     }

    public function close() {
         // your code if any
         return true;
     }

    public function read($id) {
         // your code
     }

    public function write($id, $data) {
         // your code
     }

    public function destroy($id) {
         // your code
     }

    public function gc($maxlifetime) {
         // your code
     }
 }

new SessionSaveHandler();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure how to set this up, do I need to run sessionsavehandler for every instance, every time I have session_start on the page?

Yes, you would just create a new instance of *SessionSaveHandler* <del>instead of</del> *before* calling `session_start`.

> I want to change the sesison_cache expire as well or should I do that in the class?

You are just overriding the default storage handler; the rest stays unchanged. So use `session_cache_expire` as you would before.

> If someone could please outline the steps I need to take to use this class that would be great.

As already said, you are just overriding PHP’s default session storage handler. So <del>instead of</del> *before* calling `session_start` create a new instance of your session storage handler *SessionSaveHandler*. Apart from that, nothing else is different from using PHP’s default session handler.

Comment: Hi I set this up to call the class with this in the  open function of the class $this->datetime = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
mail("mail@email.com","session opened","start: ".$this->datetime);' i'm not getting any emails though

Comment: @jimsmith Sorry, I was wrong. You need to call `session_start` anyway.

Comment: thanks I set up the session_cache_expire and session_start to run in the construct and that is running OK, but I'm still not getting anything from the open function? Should the open function run automatically when the session started? I'm not getting anything from the destroy() either

Comment: I was hoping that the destroy method would trigger when the cache expired that is why I'm using it.

Comment: @jimsmith [`session_cache_expire`](http://php.net/session_cache_expire) has nothing to do with session expiration. It just controls how long an HTTP response of an active session is considered fresh according to [HTTP caching](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-13).

Comment: edit: no worries I found it ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', 60*20);